# PHP Error Reporting - use of "^" character and the "~" character

Tags: php, error-reporting

I'm try to understand the difference between the use of the "^" character and the "~" character when setting the error_reporting values. For example I have the following in my php script:

```
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0') >= 0) {
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~ E_DEPRECATED & ~ E_USER_DEPRECATED & ~ E_NOTICE);
} else {
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
}
```

I've read the manual page at:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

but I'm now more confused than ever. Is:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~ E_DEPRECATED & ~ E_USER_DEPRECATED & ~ E_NOTICE);
```

the same as:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED ^ E_USER_DEPRECATED ^ E_NOTICE);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

those are bitwise operators: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~ E_DEPRECATED & ~ E_USER_DEPRECATED & ~ E_NOTICE);
```

would mean E_ALL and NOT E_DEPRECATED and NOT E_USER_DEPRECATED & NOT E_NOTICE

while

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED ^ E_USER_DEPRECATED ^ E_NOTICE);
```

would mean E_ALL except E_DEP.... etc.

Comment: `^` is not `or`, it's `xor`.

Comment: Thanks - so am I right in concluding that (E_ALL & ~ E_DEPRECATED & ~ E_USER_DEPRECATED & ~ E_NOTICE) produces the same result as (E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED ^ E_USER_DEPRECATED ^ E_NOTICE)?

Answer (score 0):

I think the more relevant answer to your question was listed in a comment on the [error reporting page on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php#64060) which I'll repost here:

> The example of E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE is a 'bit' confusing for those of us not wholly conversant with bitwise operators.
>
> If you wish to remove notices from the current level, whatever that unknown level might be, use & ~ instead:
>
> ```
> <?php
> //....
> $errorlevel=error_reporting();
> error_reporting($errorlevel & ~E_NOTICE);
> //...code that generates notices
> error_reporting($errorlevel);
> //...
> ?>
> ```
>
> ^ is the xor (bit flipping) operator and would actually turn notices *on* if they were previously off (in the error level on its left). It works in the example because E_ALL is guaranteed to have the bit for E_NOTICE set, so when ^ flips that bit, it is in fact turned off. & ~ (and not) will always turn off the bits specified by the right-hand parameter, whether or not they were on or off.